# Dhall double encodes %2F

Tags: urlencode, dhall

I'm using the Gitlab API that needs part of the path URL encoded when fetching files, but for some reason Dhall double-encodes my URL (example uses just google.com to minimize):

```
Welcome to the Dhall v1.41.1 REPL! Type :help for more information.
⊢ https://google.com/hello%2Fworld

Error: Remote file not found

HTTP status code: 404

URL: https://google.com/hello%252Fworld
```

According to https://docs.dhall-lang.org/howtos/migrations/Deprecation-of-quoted-paths-in-URLs.html it should indeed work with the above example, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this part of the standard, but at least the different URL in the error message looks like a bug. Can you open a ticket at https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-haskell/issues? For the reproducer it would probably be helpful to have a working URL though.